# How to append pre-existing css classes to node labels in Cytoscape JS for Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, class, cytoscape.js

I have a unified CSS theme throughout my project, although the node's CSS doesn't conform. I need to change the css label colors based on day mode and night mode, how di I achieve that?

```
this.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById(this.pageId),
    boxSelectionEnabled: false,
    autounselectify: true,
    zoomingEnabled: true,
    panningEnabled: true,
    autoungrabify: false,
    elements: this.nodes,    
    style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'width':'data(cpu)',
        'height': 'data(cpu)',
        //'shape': 'circle',
        'background-image': 'data(HealthImage)',
        'background-fit': 'contain contain',
        'background-color': '#f5f7fa',
        'label': 'data(' + this.nodeName + ')',
        'cssClass': 'form-group', //tried this didn't work
        "text-valign": "bottom",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "font-size": "12px",
        "text-margin-y": "8px"
      }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set cytoscape js style with javascript codes. Maybe you can set a timer to change the style or always check the time and set the style according to time.

http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.style

Answer (score 0):

```
this.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById(this.pageId),
    boxSelectionEnabled: false,
    autounselectify: true,
    zoomingEnabled: true,
    panningEnabled: true,
    autoungrabify: false,
    elements: this.nodes,    
    style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'width':'data(cpu)',
        'height': 'data(cpu)',
        //'shape': 'circle',
        'background-image': 'data(HealthImage)',
        'background-fit': 'contain contain',
        'background-color': '#f5f7fa',
        'label': 'data(' + this.nodeName + ')',
        'cssClass': 'form-group', //tried this didn't work
        "text-valign": "bottom",
        "text-halign": "center",
        "font-size": "12px",
        "text-margin-y": "8px"
      }
    }, {
      selector: '.day',
      style: { "text-background-color": "white" }
    }, {
      selector: '.night',
      style: { "text-background-color": "black" }
    }]
});
```

After this, you just need to add the right class to each node and you are good to go. Also, remember to remove the inactive class when adding the other class.

```
 cy.elements().toggleClass('day').toggleClass('night');  // maybe replace that with add/removeClass if this doesn't work
```